# How to make a Modal Window not movable?

Tags: java, zk

I would like a modal `Window` but NOT movable, and couldn't find any information about this behavior in document. How do I disable it?

Comment: Which platform are you using? Windows?

Comment: That is about ZK-Web-Framework it does not matter if it is Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you can use Client Side Programming to customize a not movable modal (overlapped, popup) window, the sample below create two overlapped window and make one of them not movable

```
<zk xmlns:w="client">
    <window title="center win, movable" border="normal"
        position="center,center"
        onCreate="self.doOverlapped();" />
    <window title="top win, not movable" border="normal"
        sclass="z-window-not-movable"
        position="center,top"
        onCreate="self.doOverlapped();">
        <attribute w:name="bind_"><![CDATA[
            function (a, b, c) {
                if (!this.$class.ignoremoveOverridden) {
                    this.$class.ignoremoveOverridden = true;
                    var oldImove = this.$class._ignoremove;
                    this.$class._ignoremove = function (dg, pointer, evt) {
                        var wgt = dg.control;
                        if (jq(wgt.$n()).hasClass('z-window-not-movable')) {
                            return true;
                        }
                        return oldImove.apply(wgt, arguments);
                    }
                }
                this.$bind_(a, b, c);
            }
        ]]></attribute>
    </window>
</zk>
```

References:

[Window.js](https://github.com/zkoss/zk/blob/master/zul/src/archive/web/js/zul/wnd/Window.js)

[ZK Client Side Programming](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2010/April/Client_Side_Programming)

Comment: Thank you, this does exactly what I need. I guess it is time to learn some widget customization now. :)

Answer (score 1):

If a `Window` has no header (no title, close button, ...) you can not move it.
If you want/need the head element, I am pretty sure thre is no build in way
to disable the movement. But I am interested in this too and I think this should
be added to zk tracker as a feature.
I will take a more detailed look at the `Window` component and if I find a way
to disable it, I will add this.